# How can I connect a computer to a network through a windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, ubuntu-server

I have a linux/ubuntu server that is rather loud is inconvenient to place near enough to my home network router to connect it via ethernet. It sadly has no wireless features. I also have a windows 7 desktop connected to the network via a wifi USB network adapter. It also has an ethernet port that is unused.

I have attempted to mess with the network settings on my Windows 7 desktop, and even succeeded in connecting my server to my desktop, but then the server cannot do anything that requires internet access, such as update. It is also noteworthy that my server thinks that it is assigned the same IPv4 address as my desktop via DHCP.

Is there a way to connect my server like this: Internet<->home network<-wireless->desktop<-ethernet->server? If so, how?

Else is it possible the other way around: Internet<->home network<-wireless->server<-ethernet->desktop? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable internet connection sharing on the Windows 7 desktop.

Or you can configure certain wireless routers to connect to your existing WiFi and then plug your Linux server into an ethernet port on that.  You'd have to buy something to go that route.